# How to save the albuffer data (ObjectAL) to a disk file

Tags: ios, openal

I'm trying to implement some effects to voice using ObjectAL. I successfully applied the effects and its available in the alsource's albufferdata. But the problem occurred on saving the ObjectAL buffer to the disk file. Tried to save the file but the saved file couldn't be opened as the buffer data format is different from the audio file format.  Please help me out with a way to save the data to file.